# Apply function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a function using jquery, to expand and collapse text. There are multiple instances on a page, where this has to be applied, but using this function all the instances are changed when clicked on anchor tag. I want it to be applied only for the paragraph it is clicked.

```js
(function expand() {
  $('.expanded').hide();
  $(".more, .less").click(function() {
    $(".expanded, .more").toggle();
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapsed">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostru<a href="#" class="more">Read more</a>
</div>
<div class="expanded">pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." <a href="#" class="less">Read less</a>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="collapsed">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostru<a href="#" class="more">Read more</a>
</div>
<div class="expanded">pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." <a href="#" class="less">Read less</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to target the specific elements that are associated with the click.  It is easier to do that if you modify the HTML so all targeted elements are within a common container like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="collapsed">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostru<a href="#" class="more">Read more</a>
    </div>
    <div class="expanded">pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." <a href="#" class="less">Read less</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, you can target just the appropriate elements by using `$(this).closest(".container")` to get the parent container and then use `.find(...)` in that container to find the appropriate elements that are in the same container as the click like this:

```
(function expand() {
  $('.expanded').hide();
  $(".more, .less").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest(".container").find(".expanded, .more").toggle();
  });
})();
```

---

It could be done without adding the container div, but it would make your code much more susceptible to breaking if the HTML is changed in any way so the container concept is much more robust.  It also lets you use CSS for controlling the spacing between groups rather than using `<br>` tags which is generally more flexible too.

Comment: There isn't any reason to add this event in a function. You should put the hide() inside click event before toggle and also add a prevenDefault since it's an unused anchor tag.

Comment: Worked like charm! Thank you.

Comment: @freaky - I added the `preventDefault()`.  The IIFE is something the OP had (I assume for some reason) so I didn't remove it.

Comment: @freaky The expanded should be hidden on page load and should appear only when user wants to see more text. So I did hide that part, even before click event. I have return false; in place to prevent reloading of page. Thanks!

Comment: So you don't need to wrap in a function. just call hide then declare your event. Or even better, hide with css and just use the click event.

Answer (score 2):

Isolate them:

```js
(function expand() {
  $('.expanded').hide();
  $(".more, .less").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.expandable').find(".expanded, .more").toggle();
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="expandable">
  <div class="collapsed">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostru<a href="#" class="more">Read more</a>
  </div>
  <div class="expanded">pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." <a href="#" class="less">Read less</a>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="expandable">
  <div class="collapsed">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostru<a href="#" class="more">Read more</a>
  </div>
  <div class="expanded">pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." <a href="#" class="less">Read less</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or handle `.more` and `.less` differently:

```js
(function expand() {
  $('.expanded').hide();
  $(".more").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".collapsed").next(".expanded").add(this).toggle();
  });
  $(".less").click(function() {
    var $expanded = $(this).closest(".expanded");
    $expanded.prev('.collapsed').find('.more').add($expanded).toggle();
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapsed">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostru<a href="#" class="more">Read more</a>
</div>
<div class="expanded">pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." <a href="#" class="less">Read less</a>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="collapsed">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostru<a href="#" class="more">Read more</a>
</div>
<div class="expanded">pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." <a href="#" class="less">Read less</a>
</div>
```